# Global optimization algorithm based on MapReduce

Tags: optimization, mapreduce

In the field of the intelligent swarm, there are many algorithms can find global optimization, such as Ant Colony Optimization (ACO), particle swarm optimization (PSO).

Is there any optimization algorithm implements using MapReduce which can run at Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Every algorithm can be implemented using MapReduce if you want.

Comment: And, so you know: Questions asking us to recommend specific tools, libraries, or implementations are off-topic here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. where should ask this question to get an answer in details because I need implementation (preferably in Matlab) for optimization method using MapReduce?